# Kotllin create an Arraylist of an Object

Tags: kotlin

I want to create an array list of **BaseObject** getting the data from **List< Allparkingquery>** which has a same params as BaseObject but different class names

Here is the base BaseObject

```
 data class BaseObject (

    @SerializedName("queryfor") var queryfor : String,
    @SerializedName("whichitem") val whichitem : String,
    @SerializedName("Latitude") val latitude : String,
    @SerializedName("Longitude") val longitude : String,
    @SerializedName("DateCreated") val dateCreated : String,
    @SerializedName("NumberQueried") val numberQueried : String,
    @SerializedName("CurrentState") var currentState : String
)
```

Here is the array of @SerializedName("allparkingquery") val allparkingquery : List,

```
data class Allparkingquery (

    @SerializedName("queryfor") val queryfor : String,
    @SerializedName("whichitem") val whichitem : String,
    @SerializedName("Latitude") val latitude : String,
    @SerializedName("Longitude") val longitude : String,
    @SerializedName("DateCreated") val dateCreated : String,
    @SerializedName("NumberQueried") val numberQueried : String,
    @SerializedName("CurrentState") val currentState : String
)
```

Here is where am trying to loop **List< Allparkingquery>** as populate the data into
**List< BaseObject >**

So the challange is  baseList.add(item) is showing an error. See below

```
 var baseList: List<BaseObject> = ArrayList<BaseObject>()
            response.response_data.history[0].allparkingquery.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                baseList.add(item)
            }
```

Comment: Make `baseList` a `MutableList<BaseObject>` instead of a `List<BaseObject>`.

Comment: ↓↓↓ And fix what the answer below mentions ↓↓↓

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that despite the similarities, `BaseObject` and `Allparkingquery` are not related as `Allparkingquery` does not inherit from `BaseObject`.

The justification for having a base object is lacking from your example so I'm assuming `Allparkingquery` will have a field that will differentiate it from `BaseObject` in the future, so going off that what you need to do is change `BaseObject` to an abstract class or an interface and have `Allparkingquery` inherit from it.

```kotlin
abstract class BaseObject {
    @SerializedName("queryfor") abstract var queryfor : String,
    @SerializedName("whichitem") abstract val whichitem : String,
    @SerializedName("Latitude") abstract val latitude : String,
    @SerializedName("Longitude") abstract val longitude : String,
    @SerializedName("DateCreated") abstract val dateCreated : String,
    @SerializedName("NumberQueried") abstract val numberQueried : String,
    @SerializedName("CurrentState") abstract var currentState : String
}

class Allparkingquery(
    override var queryfor : String,
    override val whichitem : String,
    override val latitude : String,
    override val longitude : String,
    override val dateCreated : String,
    override val numberQueried : String,
    override var currentState : String
) : BaseObject()
```